# Is it possible to declare a function sort in smtlib?

Tags: z3, smt, cvc4, smt-lib

For example,

```
$ z3 -in
(declare-fun f (Int Real) Int)
(assert (= f f))
(check-sat)
sat
```

This is OK.

However, I'd like to qualify it by `as`?

```
$ z3 -in
(declare-fun f (Int Real) Int)
(assert (= (as f ???) (as f ???)))
(check-sat)
sat
```

What should I fill in `???`?

It must be a sort, but what sort should I use?

I have tried `((Int Real) Int)` or `(-> (Int Real) Int)` or `(_ (Int Real) Int)`, but none of them are correct.

Is it possible to declare a function sort in smtlib?

If there is impossible to declare a function sort, how to disambiguate `f` in the following program:

```
$ z3 -in
(declare-fun f (Int Real) Real)
(declare-fun f (Int Bool) Real)
(assert (= f f))
(error "line 3 column 11: ambiguous constant reference, more than one constant with the same sort, use a qualified expression (as <symbol> <sort>) to disambigua
te f")
```

Note that if I don’t use functions, it’s no problem:

```
$ z3 -in
(declare-fun f () Int)
(assert (= (as f Int) (as f Int)))
(check-sat)
sat
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annotation

```
(as f Int)
```

is correct, even though (as you noticed) is very confusing. This annotation does *not* necessarily mean `f` is `Int`. Rather, it means `f` results in an `Int`, so it could also be a function.

This is very confusing indeed, but it follows the standard http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-r2021-05-12.pdf, page 27:

> Recall that every function symbol f is separately associated with one or more ranks, each specifying the sorts of f ’s arguments and result. To simplify sort checking, a function symbol in a term can be annotated with one of its result sorts σ. Such an annotated function symbol is a qualified identifier of the form (as f σ).

As indicated above in `(as f σ)`, the type `σ` is *the result sort* of `f`.

Note also that solver support for these annotations is rather inconsistent. For a previous discussion on this, see https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/2135

Comment: Very thanks for your answer. I have two questions:

Comment: (1) For the example of [the comment](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/2135#issuecomment-477636435) ,  this issue seems fixed, because it is no problem in the latest release z3-4.8.12. However, my example still errors. ```(declare-fun f (Int Real) Int) (assert (= (as f Int) (as f Int))) (error "line 3 column 22: unknown constant fInt```. Do you think it is a z3 bug?

Comment: (2) If `f` should be annotated with its result sort, how to disambiguate the two `f`s with different params' sorts? Do you think it is a smtlib standard bug?

Comment: SMTLib is a first-order language. You *cannot* say `(= (as f Int) (as f Int))` to start with. The error from z3 might be a bit misleading, but it's essentially telling you that your "high-order" function comparison is invalid. To express what you've written, you'd use quantification, and make sure all applications of `f` are fully saturated. This is what it means to be "first-order." I don't think there's any bug anywhere, though I do agree the standard can be much more clear on its language.

Comment: Thanks, so ideally in my 1st program `(assert (= f f))` should raise an error. Is that right?

Comment: Strictly speaking, yes. But z3 is being "liberal" here, and going beyond the SMTLib standard. If you pass it to cvc4, you'll see that it raises an error: `(error "Parse Error: a.smt2:2.15: Cannot apply equalty to functions unless --uf-ho is set.")` While solvers tend to be "standard-compliant," they extend it in various ways, not all of which is always compatible with each other.